# Why is my DataStateBehavior not working

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, expression-blend

DataStateBehavior isn't working.  Is there a trick to make it work when properties are nested?

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <ic:DataStateBehavior x:Name="DataStateBehaviorCustomIndexButton"  Binding="{Binding ViewModel.ButtonVisibleFlag, Mode=TwoWay}" TrueState="ButtonVisible" FalseState="ButtonHidden"/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out I didn't understand what value does.

I thought it was initial value, but instead it was the value that triggers a true/false.

Comment: +1, I was under the same impression as you until I read this answer!

Comment: Then what on earth is Binding for?

Comment: I could never make the darn thing work. I ended up creating my own.

Answer (score 2):

The DataStateBehavior allows you to compare a data-bound value with an expected value and go to one state if they are equal, and another state if they aren't.

So if we want to go to a state called "CountIs5" whenever our binding of the property "Count" is 5, it looks like:

```
<ei:DataStateBehavior Binding="{Binding Count}"
                      Value="5"
                      TrueState="CountIs5"
                      FalseState="CountIsNot5"/>
```

I think what is missing in understanding is the "Value" attribute.

Note:  Value can be data-bound as well.